# Importing Excel Table into a MS SQL Table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, import

I have software for STOCK and SALES that can give me an Excel price list, I wanna write a small web app that will enable users to check prices, I don't have any access to that software's database, so I wanna import that Excel data (one worksheet, 5 columns, almost 10000 rows) into an MS SQL database table, keep in mind that the price list will change few time a month so I need to re-import that price list once its been updated.

Any suggestions? or maybe I should skip using an MS SQL database and directly use the Excel sheet? if so, then how?!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go directly to SQL Server.  Let it do the heavy lifting.  If one of your users wants to export data to Excel, by all means provide such a feature.  But multi-user changes to the data should be done in SQL Server via the web.  Excel should be a local, read-only, personal copy to download and nothing else.

SQL Server can easily import an Excel spreadsheet or .csv file, especially if we're talking about a single table with five columns.  I'd still have SQL Server do all the work on the web side.

Comment: I do not have access to the database where this PRICE LIST is coming from, so my data is in Excel, now I wanna import it into MS SQL to be able to use it in a small price checking web app I wanna build.
Thx

Answer (score 0):

If you save the Excel file as a CSV, it doesn't take much of a program to convert that into SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bulk upload to upload data from excel to sql server. Please look at the link below

http://www.gyansangrah.com/ArticleContent.aspx?ID=bulk_upload_in_asp_net

Please let me know in case of any issues.